# Selecting between more than 2 rows from DB

Tags: database, postgresql

I know that I can select elements between two rows like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

Can someone tell me how can I select using one query between 4 rows like between 20 and 30 and between 40 and 50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 20 AND 30 OR id BETWEEN 40 and 50
```